# Tkinter Python 3 create_rectangle parameters - relheight,relwidth,relx,rely

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I've made an UI and I've used relheight,relwidth,relx,rely as the parameters for all my labels such as:

```
panel = Label(window, image=img,bg="#e8f3ff") 
panel.image = img
panel.place(relheight=.15,relwidth=0.0425,relx=0.785,rely=0.51)
```

But for creating rectangles, I'm using:

```
    canvas = Canvas()
    canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,2000,2000,fill="#e8f3ff")     
    canvas.create_rectangle(0,5,8000,100,outline="#110f71", fill="#004091") 
    canvas.create_rectangle(20,210,575,542,outline="#000000")                  
    canvas.create_rectangle(600,380, 750,850,outline="#000000")
    canvas.create_rectangle(600,100,778,542,outline="#000000")                    
    canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

I tried using rel parameters for create_retangle and it gave an error, so is it possible to create rectangles with borders and bg fills using relative parameters? This is because i want my UI to auto align itself when maximized.

Comment: _"i want my UI to auto align itself when maximized"_ This is what the `grid` geometry manager is for... you are in a world of pain to achieve this with `place`.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I did it using Grid and later shifted to place purposely. Isn't there any other way to get this done without using grid?

Comment: There might be, but `grid` seems the most straightforward, affordable, and flexible.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Can you edit my code above and change the pack() that I've used to grid() and make it resize?

Comment: resize to what?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Re-align automatically if maximized. All the rectangular border, fills, buttons, widgets, labels must auto align themselves with same spacing when maximized.

Answer (score 1):

> so is it possible to create rectangles with borders and bg fills using relative parameters?

No, it is not. Canvas items require absolute coordinates. You'll have to do the math yourself.